# Clubbing values of type switch

Tags: go, switch-statement, type-switch

Following code is working fine

```golang
var requestMap map[string]interface{}
for _, value := range requestMap {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        if len(v) == 0 {
            // if is empty then no need to throw NA
            return http.StatusOK, nil
        }
    case string:
        if len(v) == 0 {
            // if is empty then no need to throw NA
            return http.StatusOK, nil
        }
    }
}
```

But following code is giving `invalid argument for len function`, I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070387/how-can-i-call-len-on-an-interface)

```golang
var requestMap map[string]interface{}
for _, value := range requestMap {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case []interface{}, string:
        if len(v) == 0 {
            // if is empty then no need to throw NA
            return http.StatusOK, nil
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't this case statement enough to identify `[]interface{}` or `string` as value type ?
Why is it still considering `interface{}` as parameter of `len()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you list multiple types in a `case` of a type switch, the static type of the `switch` variable will be of the type of the original variable. [Spec: Switch statements:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Switch_statements)

> In clauses with a case listing exactly one type, the variable has that type; otherwise, the variable has the type of the expression in the TypeSwitchGuard.

So if the switch expression is `v := value.(type)`, the of `v` in the matching case (listing multiple types) will be the type of `value`, in your case it will be `interface{}`. And the builtin [`len()`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#len) function does not allow to pass values of type `interface{}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in the case of the type switch, the `v` should be converted to a slice of interface (`[]interface`) and to a `string` at the **same time**. The compiler can't decide which to use, so it revert back the value to `interface{}`, since it can be anything.